# HTML - Mouse Detection - Links

Tags: html, input, hyperlink, mouseevent

Is there a way for when the mouse has clicked on a link it calls to an input item making it appear. Then when click on anything besides the input item it makes the input item disappear again.

Edit - Added example
Edit 2 - Fixed Emample

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sch{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="">Search</a>

<form align = "center" id = "search">
    <input id = "sch" type = "text" name = "search" placeholder = "Search Here"></br>
</form>
```

Comment: Kindly post what you did till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only Display purpose you can do this by JavaScript onclick function.

So With css make your input display: none when your page load but when you click on call JavaScript and make it display:Block

But if you are looking to insert some value and save them to database continue same process and add ajax with it.

For example

```
<div>
    <a id="1">link1</a><input type="text" name="t1" class="hid" id="t1" /><br>
    <a id="2">link2</a><input type="text" name="t1" class="hid" id="t2" /><br>
    <a id="3">link3</a><input type="text" name="t1" class="hid" id="t3" /><br>
</div>
```

your CSS

```
<style>
        .hid{
   display: none;
}
    </style>
```

Your JS

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").on("click", function(){
                $("#t1").css("display","none");
                $("#t2").css("display","none");
                $("#t3").css("display","none");

                var Aid = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#t"+Aid).css("display","block");
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would know to call to the input item though.

Comment: please check updated Answer, this is just a hint which will guide you how to start but original your answer may very.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is for structuring the page, not for animating the page, so try to use **Javascript** or **jQuery** instead. try to use something like...

```
document.ready(function(){

$("a").onClick(function(){
$("sh").fadeIn(200)
});
});
```

I dont know if it is **exactly** like this, but you have the point.

**Hope, that I helped you.**